# Where should I position this onClick logic for a ReactJS component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component that is a button that opens a dialog.

```
const myComponent = () => <div><button>click me</button></div>
```

When the button is pressed I want the dialog to open.

Where should I position the `onClick` functionality (that will dispatch an action against the store to show the dialog)?

Should I use `mapStateToProps` to create a function on the props that will open the dialog, or is this overkill for such a small component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's depend on many aspects of your design:

**Is it a common button component? Do you reuse your button some where else?**

Then you should pass the onClick event and the caption of the button from props.

**Is it a button that only dispatch a function to open the dialog? Is it used to open the dialog only?**

Then you can handle that inside the component.

**If it's used to dispatch an action to a store,** then use `mapDispatchToProps` to map to the action to props.

In my opinions, no need to use store here unless you have that dialog accessible somewhere else.

Comment: Can I use `mapDispatchToProps` with a stateless functional component?

Comment: Yes, if you are dispatching an action to a store